# SSIS Combining CSV files

Tags: ssis

Im kinda new to all the SSIS stuff. And im stuck with it. i want to combine multiple CSV files and then put them into a database. The files all have the same info. Examples:

File 1

```
   Week         Text1
 22-10-2018      58
 29-10-2018      12
```

File 2

```
   Week         Text2
 22-10-2018      55
 29-10-2018      48
```

File 3

```
   Week         Text3
 22-10-2018      14
 29-10-2018      99
```

Expected result:
Result in DB

```
   Week         Text1    Text2    Text3
 22-10-2018      58        55       14
 29-10-2018      12        48       99
```

I got this far by selecting the documents, use a sort and then a join merge. For 3 documents this took me 3 sorts and 2 join merge's. I have to do this for about 86 documents.. there has to be an easier way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a helpful article here ... https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: Will there ever be four files and therefore a Text4 column? 5 files? I can pose a solution that loads multiple File1, File2, File3's into a table like that

Comment: Ye it will go up to 103 files. i dont mind if its pivoted or not aswell

Comment: I suggest a different data model.  3 columns ... Date TextXXX Value

Comment: i got so far that it now takes the week for all the files (foreach loop) and puts them into the database. It now just has to check if the 2nd column already exists, and if not create it and insert the data. if it does exists (like the column week) it should do nothing. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: you have 103 files but they will only ever have text1, text2 or text3 in them? Please explain it's not clear. Are you saying you've staged all files into three (or 103) tables?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i have 103 files. all of the files have 2 columns; the week column as specified above and a value column each and everytime with a unique column name. Real examples of names could be AI or Agile. Represented bij Text1 2 and 3 in the examples above.

i want them all into one table in the database.

Comment: OK so regardless of files, your final table will only have _four_ columns? Are there only three possible column names? Or could there be many different ones? Are you certain this is how you want to model the data? If you just put it all in a two column table that would save a lot of headaches. Dynamic columns names are not a good idea.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i could transfer the Dates (wich are a stable amount of weeks) into the columns and then add the different possibles outcomes (103 different ones) in the rows. But how could i do that for every single file?

Comment: Don't put Dates _or_ outcomes in as column names. I suggest a three column table: Date, Outcome, Count (whatever that number is). But there is a bigger modelling question here as I don't know what you are doing with this data. If I was doing this I would use a for each file loop to load the entire file (including the column name) into a staging table then merge into the final table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with KeithL, I recommend that your final table look like this:

```
Week        Outcome    Value      DateModified
=======================================================
22-10-2018     AI       58       2018-10-23 20:49
29-10-2018     AI       32       2018-10-23 20:49
22-10-2018    Agile     51       2018-10-23 20:49
29-10-2018    Agile     22       2018-10-23 20:49
```

If you want to pivot Weeks or outcomes, do it in your reporting tool.

Don't create tables with dynamic named columns - that's a bad idea

Anyway here is an approach that uses a staging table.

Create a staging table that your file will be inserted into:

*Script 1:*

```
 CREATE TABLE Staging (
      [Week]         VARCHAR(50),
      Value          VARCHAR(50),
      DateModified   DATETIME2(0) DEFAULT(GETDATE())
     )
```

Import the entire file in, including headings. In other words, when defining the file format, don't tick 'columns in  first row'

We do this for two reasons:

1. SSIS can't import files with with different heading names using the same data flow
2. We need to capture the heading name in our staging table

After you import a file your staging table looks like this:

```
Week          Value    DateModified   
=======================================
Week          Agile    2018-10-23 20:49    
22-10-2018      58     2018-10-23 20:49
29-10-2018      32     2018-10-23 20:49
```

Now select out the data in the shape we want to load it in. Run this in your database after importing the data to check:

*Script 2:*

```
SELECT Week, Value,
(SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM Staging WHERE Week = 'Week') Outcome
FROM staging 
WHERE Week <> 'Week'
```

Now add an INSERT and some logic to stop duplicates. Put this into an execute SQL task after the data import

*Script 3:*

```
WITH SRC As (
SELECT Week, Value,
(SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM Staging WHERE Week = 'Week') Outcome
FROM staging As SRC
WHERE Week <> 'Week'
)

INSERT INTO FinalTable (Week,Value, Outcome)
select  Week, Value, Outcome
FROM SRC
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM FinalTable TGT 
    WHERE TGT.Week = SRC.Week 
    AND TGT.Outcome = SRC.Outcome
    )
```

Now you wrap this up in a for each file loop that repeats this for each file in the folder. Don't forget that you need to `TRUNCATE TABLE staging` before importing each file.

*In Summary:*

1. Set up a for each file iterator
2. Inside this goes:

   - A SQL Task with `TRUNCATE TABLE Staging`;
   - A data flow to import the text file from the iterator into the staging table
   - A SQL Task with Script 3 in it

I've put the DateModified columns in the tables to help you troubleshoot.

- Good things: you can run this over and over and reimport the same file and you won't get duplicates
- Bad thing: Possibility of cast failures when inserting VARCHAR into DATE or INT

Comment: I tried this, instead of the C# under this comment because i am more confortable using SQL queries.Unfortuniatly i get an error with the insert script:

Invalid column name 'Outcome'."

i created the table FinalTable aswell with Week and value as nvarchar 50 and Outcome as nvarchar 255

https://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads9/5bceea84d293e/5bceea84d2073-Capture.PNG
This is the forloop

https://www.imgdumper.nl/uploads9/5bceea9d55303/5bceea9d54914-Capture2.PNG
And this is the dataflow

The 1st SQL is the insert into, the second one is the truncate.

Comment: Nevermind i fixed that part. by changing SRC.Outcome to Outcome because SRC does not have a column outcome. It just doest loop my files right now. It does the thing, for 1 file..

Comment: That's probably not going to work. I have to go out but I'll fix it shortly. In the meantime you need to drop all of that inside a for each file container, which is what the very first comment was about https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: it is inside a for each loop. with the name "voer alles in in trends". when i follow your link the only difference would be the file system task, but my files dont need to be moved.

Comment: i tested and it does loop all the files, just doest put them in the database.

Comment: I've edited and improved. To troubleshoot the for each file iterator, temporarily disable the truncate table step and check `staging`. Is it importing all the files or just the first one over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

You can read your file(s) using a simple C# script component (Source).

You need to add your 3 columns to output0.

1. Week as DT_Date
2. Type as DT_STR
3. Value as DT_I4

   ```
   string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines([filename]);
   int ctr = 0;
   string type;

   foreach(string line in lines)
   {
      string[] col = line.Split(',');
      if(ctr==0) //First line is header
      {
         type = col[1];
      }
      else
      {
         Output0Buffer.AddRow();
         Output0Buffer.Week = DateTime.Parse(col[0]);
         Output0Buffer.Type = type;
         Output0Buffer.Value = int.Parse(col[1]);
      }
      ctr++;
   }
   ```

After you load to a table you can always create a view with a dynamic pivot.